# counting number of records in a while loop?

Tags: php, sql

So here's my code, it selects some data from the tags table tag column, fairly basic stuff. It then echo's the result with some html.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM models.tags where tags.name ='".$_SESSION['name']."'");
$sql->execute();
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "<li><a href='#'>",$result->tag,"<span>1</span></a></li>";
}
```

In the echo part I would like to add a count of how many records have that tag, the sql would be

```
SELECT COUNT(tag) FROM models.tags WHERE tags.tag = $result->tag[current tag]
```

```
echo "<li><a href='#'>",$result->tag,"<span> <count goes here> </span></a></li>";
```

How can I conduct this second query and include the result in the while function as above?

The result will look something this (imaging html buttons):  [tag 6] [tag 4] [tag 1]

Comment: If you want to use aggregate functions, such as `COUNT()`, you should `GROUP BY`. Just add those to the first query?

Comment: That's a misuse of prepared statements. `where tags.name = ?` then `$sql->execute(array($_SESSION['name']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you actually want:

```
SELECT tagname, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM models.tags 
GROUP BY tagname;
```

You can loop through the result set to get the counts for each tag.